# How to list all folder and files in my repository

Tags: python

**My question how to show the folder in my repository beacause my code now is only showing all files in my repository and i want to see all folders and all files my problem is that i only see file**

*I want Video with all his children when i print*

```
monRepertoire="/home/administrator/Desktop/TP4/"
from os import walk
listeFichiers = []
for (repertoire, sousRepertoires, fichiers) in walk(monRepertoire):
    listeFichiers.extend(fichiers)
    print(listeFichiers)
```

Comment: Firstly that formatting is off ... I'm certain that you don't mean to print inside the for loop.  Secondly you're **capturing** files and directories, but you're only adding files (*fichiers*) to your list; the directories (*sousRepertoires*) never get used ... That all said: I'm not sure I understand what you actually are trying to achieve.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. `sousRepertoires` is right there. What do you need help with exactly? Please [edit] to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider `glob`, it allows recursive search of directories and files, and return a list of them.

```
import glob
monRepertoire="/home/administrator/Desktop/TP4/"
# use ** and set recursive=True to perform recursive search
listeFichiers = glob.glob(monRepertoire + "**", recursive=True)
print(listeFichiers)
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope the following function can help you.

```
import os

def get_files_and_folders(directory):
    return os.listdir(directory)
```

Comment: This won't recurse into subdirectories, and the wrapper function is pointless.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the wrapper function. For clarification, the reason for writing that way it's for others to easily copy over and edit themselves.